# How to Position Widgets Independently of Other Widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, position

I was Trying to Have 3 Widgets in Single page using Column, but for some reason the alignment is not working...

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      child: SwipeDetector(
        onSwipeUp: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreditScreen()));
        },

        onSwipeDown: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ManualScreen()));
        },
        
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: DarkBlue,
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: new Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/swipe_down.gif',
                    scale: 5,
                  ),
                ),

                new Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text("Menu Screen",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),

                new Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/swipe_up.gif',
                    scale: 5,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

According to the above image, I want the swipe up widget at bottom and swipe down at the top while the text in center, I Tried Many wrapping of Widgets, but nothing seems to work...
Any Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Column(
              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('assets/swipe_down.gif',
                    scale: 5,
                  ),

               Expanded(
                  child: Text("Menu Screen",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),

                Image.asset('assets/swipe_up.gif',
                    scale: 5,
                  ),
                
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks A lot Man... It worked...
Can you explain how ? just curious

Comment: Wrapping the ```Text``` widget with ```Center(...),``` , along with your source code, totally solved my problem... thanks a lot...

Comment: column item height grow with height of widget inside, so if you don't define text height(with container), it will be the height of text, if you need don't know how to the middle part is, just use expanded widget to fill up the middle part of column

Answer (score 0):

You can use Center widget for aligning widgets in center along with padding widget for giving spaces between the widgets.

```
 Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

      body: new Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,

      child:
        Center(
           child: Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
                           Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:30),
                              child: Image.asset('assets/swipe_down.gif'),
                              ),


            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:80),
              child: 
                   Text("Menu Screen",
                          style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold 
                      ),
                ),
            ),


        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:80),
          child: Image.asset('assets/swipe_up.gif'),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
     ),
   ),
```